# When count more than one put static value else keep original value in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

When I have multple values a column, I would like to display the static value `'More than one Value'` else I would like the original column value to be retained.

This gets me what I want but this limits the results to the `HAVING COUNT(B.COL3) > 1` condition:

```
SELECT
    A.COL1,
    A.COL2,
    'More than one Value' AS COL3
FROM TBL1 A
RIGHT JOIN TBL2 B ON A.TBL1-ID = B.TBL2-ID
GROUP BY A.COL1, A.COL2
HAVING COUNT(B.COL3) > 1;
```

This one is failing:

```
SELECT
    A.COL1,
    A.COL2,
    CASE WHEN COUNT (B.COL3) >1 THEN 'More than one Value' ELSE B.COL3 END AS COL3
FROM TBL1 A
RIGHT OUTER JOIN TBL2 B ON A.TBL1-ID = B.TBL2-ID
GROUP BY A.COL1, A.COL2;
```

Here is how is a mockup of the data

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | C |
| A1 | B1 | More than one Value |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `B.COL3` is a string then:

```sql
SELECT A.COL1,
       A.COL2,
       CASE
       WHEN COUNT(B.COL3) > 1
       THEN 'More than one Value'
       ELSE MAX(B.COL3)
       END AS COL3
FROM   TBL1 A
       RIGHT JOIN TBL2 B
       ON A.TBL1_ID = B.TBL2_ID
GROUP BY A.COL1, A.COL2;
```

If it is not a string then use `TO_CHAR(MAX(B.col3))`.

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tbl1 (col1, col2, tbl1_id) AS
SELECT 'A',  'B',  1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A1', 'B1', 2 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE tbl2 (col3, tbl2_id) AS
SELECT 'C',  1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C1', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C2', 2 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | C |
| A1 | B1 | More than one Value |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/mnsauiF0)

Comment: Thanks @MT0 - I gave that shot and I am getting: ORA-12704: character set mismatch

Comment: @SanJoe1980 If your `col3` data type is `NVARCHAR2` or `NCHAR` then use `N'More than one Value'` [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/a8IW_t_Z)

Comment: `B.COL3`  is a string

Comment: @SanJoe1980 What does `SELECT data_type FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE table_name = 'TBL2' AND column_name = 'COL3';` output? If it is `NVARCHAR2` or `NCHAR` then, like I said in the previous comment, use `N'More than one Value'`.

Comment: Nevermind. In was a `NVARCHAR2` & your `N'More than one Value'` did the trick. Thank you very much for the help!!!